# How to zoom in acid-state?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, acid-state

```
data Foo = Foo {
  _bar :: Map String Integer
} deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Data, Typeable)

$(deriveSafeCopy 0 'base 'Foo)

$(makeLenses ''Foo)
```

Given the above code I am under the impression that it should be possible to do this:

```
addEntry :: String -> Update Foo ()
addEntry s = zoom bar $ modify $ insert s 0
```

But GHC will complain along the lines of:

```
src/Backend.hs:39:20:
    No instance for (Functor
                       (Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed (Update Foo) ()))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed` is a type family which describes what kind of context is required during a `zoom`. It performs some special magic as you can see in the [`Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.0.1/docs/src/Control-Lens-Internal-Zoom.html). Typically a user of `zoom` would never need to see that stuff so long as they zoom in on a "typical" monad transformer stack.

`Update`, while being implemented as just `State` beneath the covers, doesn't have a zoom instance. Its implementation is not exported either so you're unable to write your own, though it'd be quite trivial since `Update` doesn't use monad transformers.

```
type instance Zoomed (Update x) = Focusing Identity
```

Comment: So there is probably no way to get this (and similar instances) into some package like `lens-acidstate`?

Comment: It'd require some more sneaky module juggling—probably an `acidstate-internal` which both `acidstate` and `lens-acidstate` would depend upon.

Comment: Would it be worth it? Or is there a way to provide `Zoomed` without relying on `lens` as it is possible with the basic `Lens` types? (This  question should probably directed directly to ekmett or the acid-state maintainers.)